# Prove that $\|\mathrm{Tr}_B(T)\|_1\le\|T\|_1$ for bounded operators $T$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace

While reading Holevo's book on Quantum information, I saw the following result: For any bounded operator $T \in \mathcal{B}(H_A \otimes H_B)$, where $H_A$ and $H_B$ are Hilbert spaces with finite dimension, we have
$$\|\mathrm{Tr}_{B}(T)\|_1 \leq \|T\|_1$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}_B(T)$ is the partial trace (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2198007/35983) for the definition in Holevo) of $T$ with respect to $H_B$. The norm here is the Trace norm defined as $\|T\|_1 = \mathrm{Tr}(|T|) = \mathrm{Tr}(\sqrt{T^*T})$.

My approach was to first show that for any operator $T$, $\mathrm{Tr}(T) = \mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{Tr}_B(T))$ and then to show $\mathrm{Tr}_B(|T|)\geq |\mathrm{Tr}_B(T)|$ (operator inequality). From the definition, I was able to show the first part easily. But the second part, which is like a Jensen inequality was elusive. Also, I'm not sure if it is true but it does hold for regular trace i.e., $\mathrm{Tr}(|T|)\geq |\mathrm{Tr}(T)|$.

Starting with the definition does not seem to help as I do not know how to work with $|Tr_B(T)|$. Could someone throw some light on this? (I appreciate hints as well as a proof if possible) Also is there an alternative, more useful way to define partial trace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof I know uses the partial trace definition via the trace, e.g. for $T\in\mathcal B_1(\mathcal H_A\otimes\mathcal H_B)$ now $\operatorname{tr}_B(T)$ is the unique operator such that $$\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{tr}_B(T)X)=\operatorname{tr}(T(X\otimes\mathbb 1_B))$$ for all $X\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H_A)$. *($\mathcal B_1$ is the trace class but no worries, in finite dimensions this is the same as $\mathcal B$)*
 The key observations are the following:

1. Every operator admits a polar decomposition $T=U|T|$ with $U$ unitary (or in infinite dimensions: $U$ partial isometry), so in particular $\|U\|=1\,$.
2. For any $X\in\mathcal B_1(\mathcal H),Y\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ one has $|\operatorname{tr}(XY)|\leq \|X\|_1\|Y\|\,$.

The rest is simple as now there exists a unitary matrix $U$, such that

$$
\|\operatorname{tr}_B(T)\|_1=\operatorname{tr}(|\operatorname{tr}_B(T)|)=\operatorname{tr}(U\operatorname{tr}_B(T))=\operatorname{tr}((U\otimes\mathbb 1_B)T)\leq \|T\|_1\underbrace{\|U\otimes\mathbb 1_B\|}_{=\|U\|\|\mathbb 1_B\|=1}=\|T\|_1\,.
$$

*(Side note that $\operatorname{tr}((U\otimes\mathbb 1_B)T)=|\operatorname{tr}((U\otimes\mathbb 1_B)T)|$ (non-negative) as we showed that it equals $\|\operatorname{tr}_B(T)\|_1$, so we can actually use the above trace inequality.)*

Comment: Superb explanation. I had gotten to the polar decomposition part but for some reason i didnt think of applying the trace inequality. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I had almost the same question but wanted to clarify one thing: May I ask about the equality $\text{tr}(U \text{tr}_B(T)) = \text{tr}((U\otimes I_B)T)$? Doesn't taking the partial trace decrease the dimension of the space and hence the left hand side of the equality is smaller by a factor of dim$(I_B)$?

Comment: The equality you are talking about is the definition of the partial trace. As for your question, observe how the matrices $\operatorname{diag}(1,2,1,10)$ and $\operatorname{diag}(3,11)$ (= the partial trace of the first matrix) have the same trace although they are of different size.